# print out 5 characters in a line bash scripting

Tags: bash

I have let say x no of char in a string.
how to print them 5 by 5?
let say

```
$x = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

I wanted to print out like this and **store it in a file**

```
abcde
fghij
klmno
pqrst
uvwxy
z
```

any idea?

edited

somepart of my code

```
# data file
INPUT=encrypted2.txt
# while loop

while IFS= read -r -n1 char
do
        # display one character at a time
    echo "$char"
done < "$INPUT"
```

Comment: What have you already tried? This is not a free coding service.

Comment: for ((i=0;i<5;i++)) do
while IFS= read -r -n1 char
do
        # display one character at a time
 echo  "$char"
done < "$INPUT"
done

Comment: @TheBlueDog aww how to reply as code?

Comment: Just edit your question to include your code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `fold` command:

```
$ echo "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" | fold -w 5
abcde
fghij
klmno
pqrst
uvwxy
z
```

Comment: +1 I love these single purpose unix commands that I have never heard of.

Comment: ok ive edited my code (basically removed my while loop and just used the fold command. it worked as charm! thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

The:

```
grep -Po '.{5}|.*' <<< "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
#or
grep -Po '.{1,5}' <<< "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" #@Cyrus
```

prints

```
abcde
fghij
klmno
pqrst
uvwxy
z
```

Or with your script

```
input=encrypted2.txt
while read -r -n5 ch
do
    echo "$ch"
done < "$input" >output.txt
```

Comment: or `grep -Po '.{1,5}'`.

Comment: @Cyrus - :) need going to sleep. Sometimes i'm overcomplicated. thanx.